# Error when building with maven: A required class was missing

Tags: maven, pom.xml

While build the maven application(2.0.4). I got the following build error in POM.xml(eclipse):

```
Execution default-resources of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources: org/apache/maven/shared/filtering/MavenFilteringException
-----------------------------------------------------
realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6
strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/NM28088/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.6/maven-resources-plugin-2.6.jar
urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/NM28088/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.4.1/plexus-utils-1.4.1.jar
urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/NM28088/.m2/repository/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar
Number of foreign imports: 1
import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
-----------------------------------------------------
(org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources:default-resources:process-resources)
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Are you trying to build with Maven 2.0.4 ? If yes why? Why not building with Maven 3? Any other error message during the build? I would assume there are warnings about not correctly fetched dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. the problem is i could not connect to internet because of security reasons. so i downloaded most of the maven plugins manually.My project is developed using JDK 1.4 and Maven 2.0.4.Actually projects build successfully but the error shows in  POM file.

Comment: <groupId>com.sanofiaventis.xenon</groupId>
 <artifactId>dpa-java</artifactId>
 <version>4.3.5</version>
 <packaging>jar</packaging>

 <name>DPA Java Module (library)</name>
 <description>DPA Java Library</description>

Comment: Error shows at  packaging tag in the above POM file snippet